# get blank page when navigating to empty path

Tags: angular

I m using latest angular version 
I need to show an overview page when user open default empty root path "**/**" and form there he can go to login page  
I ve **OverviewComponent** , **LoginComponent** and here below my route config :

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    { path: 'overview', component : OverviewComponent     }, 
    { path: '', redirectTo:'overview' , pathMatch:'full'  },
    { path: 'login', component :'LoginComponent'          },
  ] 
   ),
],
exports: [RouterModule],
 })
```

when i serve the app  i got blank page without any error and router-outlet doesn't get replaced with overviewComponent selector

Comment: Is any of your routing working? Like when you explicitly go to /login or /overview url?

Comment: /overview and /login are working .

Comment: Try : { path: '', redirectTo:'/overview' , pathMatch:'full'  }, add a / before overview

Comment: same result i got blank page

Comment: try to use guard. guard check is user authorized - go to OverView else navigate to login page

Comment: Test this please :  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/overview' },